# extract a specific string which start with "(/ " and ends with "/)" in java script from a long string

Tags: javascript

Extract a specific string which starts with "(/ " and ends with "/)" using javascript from a long string.
I tried regular expression no luck

My string as follows

> "Dear Mr./Ms. (/Name/),​Following up for the position of (/Developer/), I’d like to inquire about the progress of your hiring decision and the status of my job application. I am very eager to (/Work/) with your company.​Thanks for your time and consideration, and I look forward to hear back from you soon.​Sincerely,(/YourName/)"

Desired output = Name,Developer,Work,YourName

Comment: Show us what you tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: const regex = /[(//)]/g;
const str = "mystring";
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}

Comment: I would advise you to study [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Comment: Just try this regex `/\(\/(.*?)\/\)/g`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code

```js
let result =  "Dear Mr./Ms. (/Name/),​Following up for the position of (/Developer/), I’d like to inquire about the progress of your hiring decision and the status of my job application. I am very eager to (/Work/) with your company.​Thanks for your time and consideration, and I look forward to hear back from you soon.​Sincerely,(/YourName/)";

let ans = result.match(/\/\w+\//g);

ans = ans.map(e => e.replace(/\//g, ''));
console.log(ans);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps... assuming you have an array of words to replace said strings with this should work...

```
                var testStrings = {'one':'awesome','two':'more awesome'};
                var testStr = 'I went on an /one/ walk and found a dollar on the street /two/!';
                var newStr = testStr;
                $.each(testStrings,function(k,v){
                    console.log('k',k);
                    console.log('v',v);
                    newStr = newStr.replace('/'+k+'/',v);
                });
                console.log('testStr',testStr);
                console.log('newStr',newStr);
```

Initial String:
'I went on an /one/ walk and found a dollar on the street /two/!'

Output STring:
'Your output would be I went on an awesome walk and found a dollar on the street more awesome!'